# Creating component in SPFx webpart from command line

Tags: 2016, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

Is there any way to generate component in React from command line (similar to Angular's `ng generate`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A react component is just a `.tsx` file. So just add a new file, give it a `.tsx` extension, copy an existing component's code, change its class name and fill out the props and implementation.

I'm not aware of any way to generate it, but i don't really think it's necessary.